# comparing elements of json in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I do have a sample json as below:

```
    {
    "parent": [
        {
            "code": "333",
            "priority": {
                "p": "BB"
            }
        },
                {
            "code": "999",
            "priority": {
                "p": "BX"
            }
        },
                {
            "code": "2222",
            "priority": {
                "p": "BA"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is just a sample json. I want to compare the value of **p(priority)** and based on that return corresponding code which has highest priority. Like in above sample json, 999 is the value that I am expecting since the value of **p is BX which has highest priority**. Is there a short cut and efficient way in python since I am new to python?

Update/clarification on Question:
Since I got answer based on the assumption that p is having alphabetic value which we can prioritize. But, that is not the case. P could have 3 set of values(which are fixed for example: BX is highest priority,BB is second and BA is least). If this json has priority BX, I need to return 999, if BX is not there but BB and BA are there, I need to return BB.

This was my basic solution which works but I think it has to many conditions:

```
code = None
for item in json['parent']:
    if item['priority'] is not None and item['priority']['p'] is not None and item['priority']['p'] == 'BX' \
            and item['code'] is not None:
        code = item['code']
    if item['priority'] is not None and item['priority']['p'] is not None and item['priority']['p'] == 'BB' \
            and item['code'] is not None and code is not 'BX':
        code = item['code']
    if item['priority'] is not None and item['priority']['p'] is not None and item['priority']['p'] == 'BA' \
            and item['code'] is not None and code is not 'BX' and code is not 'BB':
        code = item['code']
```

Comment: Use the `sorted` function with a `key` that returns the `p` priority.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilise the `argmin` function from numpy:

```
import numpy as np

json = {
    "parent": [
        {
            "code": "333",
            "priority": {
                "p": "B"
            }
        },
                {
            "code": "999",
            "priority": {
                "p": "A"
            }
        },
                {
            "code": "2222",
            "priority": {
                "p": "C"
            }
        }
    ]
}

highest_prio_ind = np.argmin([x['priority']['p'] for x in json['parent']])
print(json['parent'][highest_prio_ind]['code'])
```

which returns the wanted `999`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's builtin function `min()` ([doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#min)) with custom `key=`:

```
json_data = {
    "parent": [
        {
            "code": "333",
            "priority": {
                "p": "B"
            }
        },
                {
            "code": "999",
            "priority": {
                "p": "A"
            }
        },
                {
            "code": "2222",
            "priority": {
                "p": "C"
            }
        }
    ]
}

item = min(json_data['parent'], key=lambda k: k['priority']['p'])
print(item['code'])
```

Prints:

```
999
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's just take your JSON Object as a variable and sort it.

```
parent = [
        {
            "code": "333",
            "priority": {
                "p": "B"
            }
        },
                {
            "code": "999",
            "priority": {
                "p": "A"
            }
        },
                {
            "code": "2222",
            "priority": {
                "p": "C"
            }
        }
    ]
```

To parse and sort the same there is a simple solution of lambda function.

```
parent = sorted(parent, key=lambda k: k['priority'].get('p', 0), reverse=False)
```

This will give you output something like this..

```
{'code': '999', 'priority': {'p': 'A'}}
{'code': '333', 'priority': {'p': 'B'}}
{'code': '2222', 'priority': {'p': 'C'}}
```

You can even turn into reverse by just doing `reverse=True`.

To get the value directly just find the code value of first element.

```
print(parent[0]['code'])
```

This will give you `999`